# Get status code after return in Web Api Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I wonder if there is any way of getting the status code that a controller has returned after the return statement. Let me explain. I have the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Order order)
{
   try 
   {
      // some code
      return Created();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      // some code  
      return InternalServerError(e)
   }
   finally
   {
      // Here I want to know if I've returned Created or InternalServerError
   }
}
```

I know I can declare a variable before the try, assign it in try and catch blocks and read later in the finally. This is the solution I'm using now but I'm looking for a more *elegant* one.

I saw there is a property within the controller, `ActionContext.Response.StatusCode`, that seems to be what I'm looking for, but `ActionContext.Response` is null at the time the finally block is executing

Comment: Did you try `this.Response.StatucCode`?

Comment: My controller is inheriting from `ApiController` and there is no `Response` property (when I type `this.` the Intellisense doesn't show me that property)